# Does importing only a single function also runs other functions in that file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, node-modules

I have this code in the file `bmiCalculator.ts`:

```js
import { isNotNumber } from './utils';

export default function calculateBmi(height: number, weight: number) {
  const bmi = weight / Math.pow(height / 100, 2);

  if (bmi < 18.5) {
    return 'Underweight';
  } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25) {
    return 'Normal (healthy weight)';
  } else {
    return 'Overweight';
  }
}

const parseArguments = (args: string[]) => {
  if (args.length < 4) throw new Error('Not Enough Arguments');

  if (args.length > 4) throw new Error('Too many arguments');

  if (!isNotNumber(args[2]) && !isNotNumber(args[3])) {
    return {
      height: Number(args[2]),

      weight: Number(args[3]),
    };
  } else {
    throw new Error('Arguments are not of the correct type');
  }
};

const { height, weight } = parseArguments(process.argv);

console.log(calculateBmi(height, weight));
```

And also this code in the file `index.ts`:

```js
import express from 'express';

import calculateBmi from './bmiCalculator';

const app = express();

app.get('/hello', (_req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello Full Stack!');
});

app.get('/bmi', (req, res) => {
  const height = Number(req.query.height);

  const weight = Number(req.query.weight);

  const bmi = calculateBmi(height, weight);

  res.send({ weight, height, bmi });
});

const PORT = 3002;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

I get the following error when running the Express server code in `index.ts`:

```markdown
Error: Not Enough Arguments
```

I am not importing and using the `parseArgument` function in `index.ts` so why is this happening? I am only importing and using the `calculateBmi` function into that file. At the moment, I can only run the code by commenting out the non-exported code in `bmiCalculator.ts`.

Comment: Yes, it executes the imported file.

Comment: `I am not running the parseArgument function.` You are running it here `const { height, weight } = parseArguments(process.argv);`.

Comment: `Does importing only a single function also runs other functions in that file?` No, it runs no function at all, it runs the _file_.

Comment: Please remember to [format your code](/help/how-to-ask). Even if you don't format your code _yourself_, when asking others to read it it is common courtesy to at the very least run your code through an auto-formatter so folks can actually easily understand what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as soon as you import a module (here the module is just a file), it is executed.

If the module contains *only* exported function declarations, then there is no *side effect*.

If the module contains some root level *expressions* (like `const { height, weight } = parseArguments(process.argv);` in your case), they are executed. In particular, you should see your next `console.log` printing.

Comment: *'If the module contains only exported objects, then there is no side effect.'* This is an overly broad statement and one exported object *could* mutate another or cause further side effects.

Comment: @pilchard it is true that it could be misleading, in the sense that the object creation could hide other expressions, which can potentially lead to such side effect. I will be more specific to this case.